# Create like button with Laravel with Cookies and table

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to create a "like" button. Only, I would like everyone, without having an account, to "Like" an article.

In my table for an article, can I add a "like" field and with Ajax, increment the field by +1?

Will it create a security problem?

Is it a good idea to use a cookie for this?

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Protection using only cookies is pretty easy to bypass.** One person or some kind of robot would be able to give lots of "Likes" for each article.

You can block posiblity for giving multiple "likes" based on user's ip. So basically create another table with fields like:

```
"article_id"
"user_id" (nullable)
"ip" (nullable)
```

For registered users just fill user_id field. For annonymus users fill ip field and before adding new record to database check if record with given ip exists.

Use relation in your model for likes to count them easily:

```
$this->likes->count();
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. I understand how to break down the problem. It's a good solution, I had not thought to store the IP in this way.

Answer (score 1):

With Cookie data it is simple for like but the attacker clear the browser history and make more like for that article.
Make some techniques like insert like with ip address or mac address into db but it also have some bug, because they change the proxy ip and put a like for that.
Simple solution is make like from social network like google like or facebook like.This will be a unique like for that article.
I think this will help you.
I apologize if any wrong in my answer.